# Warp the index file in Nodejs with try and catch

Tags: node.js, try-catch

In my production env when an error is thrown in a docker container, it just kills the container but doesn't log the error. the only way I can log that error is to warp all the code in the index file with try-catch and then console it. 
Does anyone know how costly it is performance-wise to warp all the code in a try-catch block in Nodejs?

Comment: Probably none, unless an error is thrown, which takes a tiny bit of resources to unwind the call stack, but that's completely negligible unless it's done an unreasonably huge number of times in short succession

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't care about the performance of the error thrown because in my API routes I do try catch to not kill the process. the index try-catch is only for errors that are not API based like bad package code etc...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any performance degradation when you wrap it in `try..catch`. Infact it is a best practice to handle your errors. Not handling means you are prone to errors and unexpected shut down of your applications. You should also have a look why the error is coming and try to fix the root problem. You can also take help of
inbuilt `unhandledRejection` listener to see all your unhandled errors.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
  // Application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection